# Form is being submitted in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

The below form is being submitted even when its `txt_approver` is empty.
But it works well in firefox/chrome?
I get no error, what could be the issue?

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["warningnotice"]["txt_approver"].value;
    alert(x);
    if (x == null || x == "") {
        alert("Please enter a name to send a email to ");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
<form method="post" action="travel.cfm" id="commentForm" name="warningnotice" onsubmit=" return validateForm()">
<td ><input type="text" name="txt_approver" class="get_empl"  required data-error="#errNm35"></td>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit"   value="Submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Are both alerts firing?

Comment: Did you try without the alert()?

Comment: yes the alert are firing, and i have try without

Comment: FYI: value is not going to be null so that check is useless.

Comment: Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: I would start by separating your HTML from your JavaScript. Use external JavaScript.

Comment: When I test that code in IE11 it says "This is a required field" without calling validateForm. Are you sure this is the same code you have the problem with?

Answer (score -3):

You are using the name attribute to locate the form and the textbox in JavaScript. This is not what the name attribute is for. The id attribute is for this.

Instead of:

```
 document.forms["warningnotice"]
```

and

```
 <input type="text" name="txt_approver" ...
```

Those lines should be:

```
 document.forms["commentForm"]
```

and

```
 <input type="text" name="txt_approver" id="txt_approver"...
```

And, instead of `document.forms`, use:

```
 var form = document.getElementById("commentForm");
 var tb = document.getElementById("txt_approver");
```

Also, instead of:

```
   if (x == null || x == "")
```

You can just use:

```
   if (!String.trim(x))
```

Because an empty textbox will produce an empty string "" and an empty string, converted to a boolean (which an if statement looks for) will be false, but a populated one, will convert to true.

Lastly, you probably don't want to have your submit button have a name attribute at all because when the form is submitted, the value of the submit button will be submitted along with the other form elements, which probably is not what you want.

The following JS Fiddle shows the code that is working for me in IE 11: https://jsfiddle.net/x0rbnL5s/

Comment: What's wrong with `document.forms`? And are you sure about fetching by `id` in that collection? The spec shows them accessed by `name`.

Comment: document.forms certainly can work, but it is a much older technique. The name attribute is used for submitting the form element along with its value. Without a name, the element will not submit its data when the form is submitted. ID is the proper way to reference any DOM element by a statically created indentifier. Too bad folks just down vote without trying the solution!

Comment: Also, the problem is with IE 11 and we all know how standards compliant IE is!

Comment: I can't test IE11 right now. So in your demo, the form isn't available by name via `document.forms`? That would surprise me. IE does quite well with standards compliance. Also, it surprises me that `String.trim()` works in IE. Maybe they added it, but it's a non-standard Firefox feature, which I think is deprecated.

Comment: What I can tell you is that IE (all versions) is well-known to NOT follow standards (this is why MS has ended it and has created Edge). Simply changing the code to access the textbox element via an id made the code work for me in IE 11 and since the sole purpose of id is for element identification (which is not the purpose of name), this makes perfect sense.  String.trim() was just a suggestion - not related to the problem.